# How do I use Python code for moving files

Tags: python, move, shutil

I have 5 files and they exist in 5 different locations

I would like to write a piece of code preferably in Python(I am a newbie) and the code should check all these 5 folders and code should check if the file exists, if it does, it should move over all those files from different locations to a single shared drive location. I tried the below URL and used import shutil, this worked but this is for one or many files from the same location to another location. Any pointers, thoughts, suggestions on how I can do this will be greatly appreciated.

https://linuxhint.com/move-file-to-other-directory-python/

Answer (score 1):

Speaking just about principles on how to solve your problem without writing any code:

From the code you linked, you have a solution for copying one file at a time. Moving that code inside a function will let you easily re-use it for many different input files, and even more than one destination file. You can define the file(s) to be copied and the destination folder as arguments.

Python's `os` library is great for operating system actions like checking [if file exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile), [making the target directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) if needed, just to name a few that might be useful. But this is just one tool for getting there, you'll likely see a few different but valid answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try Pathlib ->

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

inp_file_paths = [Path('input_file_path_1'),
                  Path('input_file_path_2'),
                  Path('input_file_path_3')]

destination_path = Path('destination_path')


def check(inp_files):
    for file in inp_files:
        if file.exists() == False:
            print(f'file = {file.name} doesn\'t exists please check the path')
            inp_files.remove(file)
    return inp_files


def move_files(inp_files):
    try:
        for file in inp_files:
            dest_path = destination_path / file.name
            shutil.copy(file, dest_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Exception {e} occurred while moving the file {file.name}')


inp_file_paths = check(inp_file_paths)
move_files(inp_file_paths)
```